# How do I make 14.04 stable on my E machine

Tags: upgrade

How do make 14.04 stable on my old machine (E machine 1624) have 13.10 currently. I have downloaded from the Ubuntu site via an image on disk, external HD all is fine until I log in then desktop freezes have to hard re-boot ... process starts again.

Answer (score 0):

Download 14.04 .iso image from ubuntu.com. Burn .iso onto flash drive by using ubuntu cd burner application.  Boot your computer with your flash drive and see if it is stable. If so install it by clicking install icon on your desktop.